# Cannot installing node-sass --save-dev / npm ERR! network

Tags: node.js, npm, sass

;)

After installing `nodeJs`, creating package.json (npm init) I wanted to install node-sass (npm install node-sass --save-dev) and an error occurred.

> "This is a problem related to network connectivity. In most cases you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 'proxy' config is set properly".

My `proxy=null`. I tried this command with `-d`, tried to clean cache, update npm and nothing. All the time the same error. Some idea? :)

here is the error response:

```
    Natours ania$ npm install node-sass --save-dev
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/asynckit/-/asynckit-0.4.0.tgz failed, reason: read ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Ania/.npm/_logs/2018-05-16T17_07_41_343Z-debug.log
```

Comment: no firewall actually

Comment: installation stops at 'extract:lodash: sill extract is-builtin-module@1.0.0'

Comment: its not a company firewall issu its on my personal laptop

Comment: can you check if you can access this file from browser https://registry.npmjs.org/asynckit/-/asynckit-0.4.0.tgz ?